# How to create private arrays in OpenMP

Tags: arrays, c, multithreading, openmp

I want to multithread a for loop for some of my C code, but I'm not really sure how to a create a bunch of private arrays for each thread in C. When I use C++. I just give it like; `#pragma omp parallel firstprivate(std::vector)`, but I'm not sure how I do it in C as I pass a ptr that points to the array to the function as an argument. If I were to just do `firstprivate(int* array)`. I would then get a bunch of ptrs that all point to the same array, but I won't get a bunch of threads that all work on their separate arrays.

My problem looks something like;

```c
void pbfs(int n, int* ver, int* edges, int* p, int* dist, int* S, int* T)
{
    int i, j;          // Loop indices
    int v, w;          // Pointers to vertices
    int num_r, num_w;  // Number of vertices in S and T, respectively
    int* temp;        // Temporary pointer

    ...

    while (num_r != 0) {               // Loop until all vertices have been discovered
        for (i = 0; i < num_r; i++) {           // Loop over vertices in S
            v = S[i];                      // Grab next vertex v in S
            for (j = ver[v]; j < ver[v + 1]; j++) { // Go through the neighbors of v
                w = edges[j];                // Get next neighbor w of v
                if (p[w] == -1) {            // Check if w is undiscovered
                    p[w] = v;                  // Set v as the parent of w
                    dist[w] = dist[v] + 1;       // Set distance of w
                    T[num_w++] = w;            // Add w to T and increase number of vertices discovered
                }
            }  // End loop over neighbors of v
        }  // End loop of vertices in S
        temp = S;  // Swap S and T
        S = T;
        T = temp;
        num_r = num_w; // Set number of elements in S
        num_w = 0;     // Set T as empty
    } //  End loop over entire graph
}
```

I'm thinking that having a pragma for the 2nd for loop would speed up this function. The problem is that `T[num_w++] = w;` is not safe. Was thinking each thread having their own copy of T, then merge T. I'm not exactly sure how to merge all the T's after either.

Comment: The 2nd loop has a very small workload, most probably the parallel overheads will be far much bigger than the gain by parallelization. What is the typical number of vertices/neighbors? If you create a [mre] (using typical numbers) we can help you how to parallelize your code.

Comment: What is your main goal? To have a fast code or to learn how to use OpenMP?

Comment: My goal is to learn OpenMP, not necessarily having fast code. I'm basically trying to take my BFS code and multithread it and see how it works out :)

Comment: Well, you have chosen a very complex problem to study openmp....

Answer (score 2):

To protect `T[num_w++] = w;` inside a parallel loop you have 2 options:

1. Use atomic operations:

```
int local_num_w;
#pragma omp atomic capture
local_num_w=num_w++;
T[local_num_w] = w;
```

2. Use a local array (`local_T`) and a local counter (`local_num_w`) for each thread, fill that local array, and merge all the local arrays to the shared `T` array.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{ 
   int local_T[T_SIZE];
   int local_num_w=0;
   #pragma omp for
   for(...) {       
      ....    
      local_T[local_num_w++] = w;            
   }

   int index;   //starting index in T array
   #pragma omp atomic capture
   {index = num_w; num_w += local_num_w;}
   
   //copy the local array to T
   for(int i=0;i<local_num_w;++i)
     T[index+i]=local_T[i];
}
```

Depending on the actual problem either option 1 or option 2 will be faster. Note that the workload is probably very small in your example, and OpenMP has a significant overhead, so I would not be surprised if the serial version would be the fastest choice in your case. Note also that when you read/write to arrays `p` and `dist` you have to use atomic operations to avoid data race.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but trying to implement this myself seems to lock up. This is how my implementation looks like. https://pastebin.com/U348ABg6

Comment: My question is the following: for a given `i` the `v` and `w` are unique OR for different `i`  can result the same `v` or  `w` value? In other words is `i->v` and `i->w` are injective?

Comment: For each `i` we pick a different item in the "queue" or the array here. So for each i. we would have a different `v`. I'm not 100% sure about `w`, incase some vertex share edge with another vertex, but I don't think it is. At the end we get a new "queue" with the same operations.

Comment: I think it cannot be parallelized efficiently if `w` is not different. In this case `critical` section have to be used: https://godbolt.org/z/vMqMW3Kze

Comment: Did you mean to check `if (p[w] == -1) {` twice?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. After the first check an another thread can modify its value, so inside a critical region I have to check it again.  To avoid such checks is important to be certain that `i->w` is injective. In this respect this line `dist[w] = dist[v] + 1;` is also very problematic. You may read `dist[v]` atomically, but an another thread can modify its value before you finish updating `dist[w]`. I do not know your algorithm you can think about it if it is a problem/can happen.  Therefore it is very important to know the exact connections between `i`, `v` and `w`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243431/discussion-between-laci-and-megamagnum).